# UK Visa signature at appointment

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, paperwork

I'm applying for a skilled worker UK visa. I had my biometrics appointment.

The document checklist says I should not sign it until I am "at my appointment". Does that just mean to not sign it until after the biometrics? i.e. I should sign the checklist, then mail it in with all my supporting documents?

Or does that mean there is another appointment at which I will sign the checklist?

EDIT: I signed it and mailed it in. I'll have an update in 15 days or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signing it and mailing it in was correct. This worked.